# Is there another representation for $x^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I started wondering about this the other day. Since the following have their own alternate representations. $$\begin{align*} \displaystyle\large x+x=2x & \
\frac{x}{x}=1 & xx=x^2\end{align*}$$

Can $x^x$ be represented in some other way? Thanks.

Comment: It could be written in many different ways algebraically. for example  $x^x=\sqrt{x^{2x}}$

Comment: $x/x=1$ is not true when $x=0$, careful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's called [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). We can write $x^x$ as $^{2}x$.

There's actually a whole chain of these iterated operators, such as the (rather) famous Knuth up-arrow notation. The page I linked to has quite a few examples if you are interested.

Answer (score 11):

$$e^{x\log(x)}$$

This is a nice way to represent it if you want to differentiate it, since you can then just apply the standard differentiation rules.

Something like $$x^{x^x}$$ will be represented as $$e^{e^{x\log(x)}\log(x)}$$